# Load 2D vector from CSV file (73x74496 data size)

Tags: c++, arrays, csv, vector

I want to read csv file that the data is only numbers, the size of the data is (73x74496), and I want to load the data to vector sample which is in the code as follows. I would like to make sample[73][74496] vector. After that, I will do signal processing with sample[73][74496]. However, I cannot load the data of csv file to sample[73][74496] vector. Could you help me?

```
int main()
{
    //float data[38][27];
    double** data = new double[73][74496];
    std::ifstream file("NAimg_20101026_145727.csv");

    for (int row = 0; row < 73; ++row)
    {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(file, line);
        if (!file.good())
            break;

        std::stringstream iss(line);

        for (int col = 0; col < 74496; ++col)
        {
            std::string val;
            std::getline(iss, val, ',');
            if (!iss.good())
                break;

            std::stringstream convertor(val);
            convertor >> data[row][col];
        }
    }
    std::cout << data[1][1] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, provide a minimal runnable example.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but relative paths will always be relative to the current working directory path. So you don't need `base_dir` unless it's *different* from the `current_path()`.

Comment: I modified the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the size of the csv file and it doesn't have to be dynamic it might be better to use a plain array instead of a vector. You are basically creating a new vector object for each row of the csv file. Since your data samples are doubles you could do something like this:

```cpp
double **data = new double *[width];
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) 
{
    data[i] = new double[height];
}
```

Then use fstream to read the csv line by line, split on commas and populate the big array.

EDIT: With your code, this should now work:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const int width = 73;
    const int height = 74496;

    //initialize
    double **data = new double *[width];
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        data[i] = new double[height];
    }

    std::ifstream file("NAimg_20101026_145727.csv");

    for (int row = 0; row < 73; ++row)
    {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(file, line);
        if (!file.good())
            break;

        std::stringstream iss(line);

        for (int col = 0; col < 74496; ++col)
        {
            std::string val;
            std::getline(iss, val, ',');
            if (!iss.good())
                break;

            data[row][col] = std::stod(val);
        }
    }
    std::cout << data[1][1] << std::endl;

    //cleanup
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        delete data[i];
    }

    delete[] data;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I change the code follow your suggestion. But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine how it `std::ifstream` interprets commas but saying that they too
are just white space. Once that is done the rest falls easily into place.

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <locale>
#include <vector>

namespace
{
struct CommaIsWhitespaceToo : std::ctype<char>
{
   static auto makeTable()
   {
      static std::vector<mask> v(classic_table(), classic_table() + table_size);
      v[','] |= space;
      return v.data();
   }
   CommaIsWhitespaceToo() : ctype(makeTable()) {}
};
}  // namespace

int main()
{
   int const kRows = 73;
   int const kCol  = 74496;
   std::vector<double> data;
   data.reserve(kRows * kCol);
   std::ifstream file("NAimg_20101026_145727.csv");
   file.imbue(std::locale(file.getloc(), new CommaIsWhitespaceToo));
   data.assign(
      std::istream_iterator<double>(file), std::istream_iterator<double>());
   assert(data.size() == kRows * kCol);  // Just make sure we got them all. Not
                                         // too many and not too few
   std::cout << data[(1 * kCol) + 1] << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

An alternative body where the `data` type uses `[]` access can be done
like:

```cpp
int main()
{
   constexpr int kRows = 73;
   constexpr int kCol  = 74496;

   using Row  = std::array<double, kCol>;
   using My2D = std::array<Row, kRows>;

   My2D data;
   std::ifstream file("NAimg_20101026_145727.csv");
   file.imbue(std::locale(file.getloc(), new CommaIsWhitespaceToo));
   for(auto& row : data)
      for(auto& col : row)
         file >> col;
   std::cout << data[1][1] << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bo R, thanks for your code. Is it make data to 2D like data[73][74496]. I need 2D array.

Comment: I'll see if I can update with an addition that forces you to access with the `data[row][col]` syntax.

Comment: Yes, I need a code to make output like std::cout << data[row][column] << std::endl; Here row is 73 and column is 74496